# Remote VPS for Ruby on Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vps

My idea is to use a remote VPS for Rails development.
When I run rails s, I used to see a message that my IP is not in a list of allowed IPs, so I added it in config development.rb using `config.web_console.whitelisted_ips`. Now I do not see any errors, and console says that my views are rendered, but I can not see anything in browser. 
Did somebody set up rails 5 as a development environment on a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

1. When start your server, binding it. 
   Rails s -b 0.0.0.0
2. Allow specific port / turn off your firewall.

Hope this help

Comment: I tried at home, and it works very well. But seems a dynamic IP addresses on my work. But from another side, server is remote, and our network dynamic IPs should not affect... Will check tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: Aw, your VPS IP is dynamic?

Comment: no, my vps IP is not dynamic. I can easily run rails s at home and app appears at mydomain:3000, but at work when I try to run my app on remote server, puma says that there is an IP which is no whitelisted (and which is no my VPS IP). When I add that IP in the white list, no warning message appears, and server logs say that my app works correct and respond on requests from mydomain:3000. But there is nothing in the browser when I visit mydomain:3000.

Comment: Got it. Hope you can fix it :)

Comment: strange, even if I run app in production mode, is still not accessible from browser. A VPN extention for Chrome helped me, and now page opens